# Getting `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'` after `npm update`

Tags: angular

Before I ran `npm update` everything worked fine, after I am getting:

> ...error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'

What I am trying to do is to access the `module.id`.

*tsconfig.json*:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I bet something small is missing somewhere, or I have to run few more commands to make it work.. can someone collaborate on it please?

Comment: Shouldn't it be tsconfig.json?

Comment: @rrd, typo detected! However in project it was `.json`, so the problem is not there.

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration file name is wrong it should be tsconfig.json. so it is unable to find the typescript installed. change it as tsconfig.

Install typescript globally,

```
typings install dt~node -g --save
```

Comment: Nope, that one was just a typo :)

Comment: `'typings' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Neither `npm typings install dt~node --g --save` works. Neither `npm install dt~node --g --save`: `npm ERR! 404 Not Found: dt~node@latest`.

Comment: npm i @types/node --save-dev or npm i @types/node --global

Comment: well.. installed successfully and yet it fails.

Comment: thats strange try removing everything and install again rm -rf node_modules
npm install

Comment: Nope. Wiped out entire `node_modules` folder, reinstalled using `npm install`, ran `npm i @types/node --global` and getting exactly the same error.

Comment: can you change the module to  "module": "es2015", instead of   "module": "commonjs",

Comment: Does not help as well. I guess I have to declare `module.id` variable somewhere globally?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182432/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-sereja-bogolubov).

Comment: Also, the flag should be `-g` or `--global`